# How to listen the Change of the HashMap's specific key's Value in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, hashmap, observer-pattern

I have to wait till the `HashMap` key's value change from another thread and have to continue the request processing after that.

Comment: The easiest way is to subclass `HashMap` and adjust the `put` method so that it notifies you somehow.

Comment: How that notification part need to implements?

Comment: Have a look at `Observer` and `Observable`

Answer (score 1):

I think the most flexible solution will be to implement the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

[image]

**Note** that build-inn interfaces `Observer` and `Observable` are deprecated since JDK version 9. Even if you are using Java 8 don't use them. The problem with them is that their names as well as the method name `update()` of the `Observer` don't tell anything to the reader of the code about the event that was triggered and what kind of actions might follow.

Ass you can see from the diagram, the **subject** should contain a *collection* of **observers** (or *listeners*).

The subject in your case should be class contains a `HashMap` updates of which you want to listen. Don't extend the map, wrap it with your class instead. Because if you choose to extend `HashMap` your code will become dependent on its implementation. And any changes in the `HashMap`, for instance, new methods were added or existing were improved could break your code (*this topic is covered in the book "Effective Java" by Joshua Blochtake, have a look at it for more information*).

So let's say we have a class `OrderManager` that maintains a map of `Order`s. This class will be a ***subject***.

A couple of services like `BillingManager`, LoggingManager`and maybe some more needs to notified new order was added. These are our ***observers***. All these classes an interface, let's say`OrderAddedListener`that defines a single method`onOrderAdded(Order order)`, that's the event we are interested in.

***Note**, if you need to listen to other events like removal or update, you need to define a new interface with a method responsible for that for every target event as the Interface segregation principle suggests.*

`OrderManager` has to have a collection of *observers*. When a new order is being added, subject iterates through the collection of observers and invokes `onOrderAdded()` method on each of them.

In order to add an observer that need to listen to the order-added event `OrderManager` has to define a method to register it, and it's also good practice to add another one to unregister the observer that has registered to be able to remove it when you no longer need it.

#### Asynchronous processing

**Note**, that in this example, events are being processing in the *same thread*. If actions performed by observers are costful or might block the thread, in order to fire them asynchronously you can create a class that will implement `Runnable` and hold references to the *observer* and *event* (*order the was added/updated*), and method `run()` will trigger the observer. And when a new event occurs, `OrderManager` instead of invoking `onOrderAdded()` on each observer should create a new instance of that class implementing runnable by passing an *observer* and a *new order* to its constructor and then create and fire a *new thread*.

It's a simplified approach. But I guess it'll give an understanding of the general idea.

#### Implementation example

That how it might look like:

```
public class OrderManager {
    private Map<Long, Order> orderById = new HashMap<>();
    private Set<OrderAddedListener> listeners = new HashSet<>();
    
    public void addOrder(Order order) {
        // notifying observers
        listeners.forEach(observer -> observer.onOrderAdded(order));
        
        orderById.put(order.getId(), order);
    }
    
    // more methods like removeOrder(), getOrderCount() etc.
    
    public boolean registerOrderAddedListener(OrderAddedListener listener) {
        return listeners.add(listener);
    }
    
    public boolean unregisterOrderAddedListener(OrderAddedListener listener) {
        return listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}

public interface OrderAddedListener {
    void onOrderAdded(Order order);
}

public class LoggingManager implements OrderAddedListener {
    private Logger logger;
    
    @Override
    public void onOrderAdded(Order order) {
//        logger.log();
        System.out.println("Log message has been written");
    }
}

public class BillingManager implements OrderAddedListener {
    private BillingService billingService;
    
    @Override
    public void onOrderAdded(Order order) {
//        billingService.sendBill(order);
        System.out.println("A bill has been sent");
    }
}
```

`main()` - a simple demo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OrderManager orderManager = new OrderManager();
    orderManager.registerOrderAddedListener(new LoggingManager());
    orderManager.registerOrderAddedListener(new BillingManager());
    orderManager.addOrder(new Order());
}
```

**Output**

```
A log message has been written
A bill has been sent
```

Comment: I need a way to trigger the function automatically when change happen

Comment: @RegReg Evens will be fired automatically when a method that changes the map (`addOrder()` in the example above) will be invoked.

Comment: @RegReg In short, my suggestion is to wrap a *map* with a special class (a ***subject***) which will be in control of every action done on that *map* (i.e. *map* can be changed **only** through the methods of that class).  So that it'll fire an *event* for each ***registered observer*** automatically with every invocation, of the method that changes the map. Can you clarify why you don't consider that *observers* will be triggered automatically?

Comment: @RegReg If you have in mind something particular in mind, maybe you can share it in the question, maybe you can provide a pseudocode (just to represent the overall idea of what you need) in order to be on the same page?